# Why can't I disable ARC (per single-file)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to use the compiler flag -fno-objc-arc but it does not work for me.
I put it in the right place, under build phases ---> compile sources ---> compiler flags.
Xcode is still giving me a ARC dealloc error even though I put that flag under the file that should not use ARC. I don't know what to do but this happens on every project I try, not just this one. I have restarted Xcode and cleaned the project but have not come up with a solution.

Does anyone know how to fix my problem?

Edit: I re-added the files that were giving me errors and it worked out just fine!
I'd still know why this happens as it's not the first time it has happened to me.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebooting yet? Might help. (command-shift-k)

Answer (score 0):

That error will continue to appear until after you set that compiler flag.  The test of whether -fno-objc-arc "took" is if the app builds or not.  If a file is compiled with ARC and you call release/retain/dealloc/etc, the program will simply fail.  When you're editing the file, Xcode may still give you erroneous error messages that you just have to ignore.